# Vim refuses to start with "error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.14" after upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: vim, shared-library, perl

After I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 vim refuses to start, showing the following error:

```
vim: error while loading shared libraries: libperl.so.5.14: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Now, I reinstalled perl, I checked `/usr/lib` for `libperl.so.5.14` file, there are three:
`libperl.so.5.14`, `libperl.so.5.14.2` and `libperl.so`. Yet I still get this error. Why doesn't it see perl?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling `vim`? Is this a 32 or 64bit system? Could you show us the output of `ls -l /usr/lib/libperl.so.5.14`?

Comment: I had a similar problem, but there was no `libperl.so.5.14` in my case. I reinstalled `vim-gtk`, then reinstalled `libperl`, no dice. Symlinking `libperl.so.5.18` to `5.14` made `vim` work again eventually.

Comment: The version of vim in 14.04 should be linked against `libperl.so.5.18`, not `libperl.so.5.14`. Which vim package(s) do you have installed and are they from official repos or from a PPA?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had Vim installed manually from sources. For that reason, after the Ubuntu upgrade, some dependencies were broken. Solved by compiling and installing vim from source.

Answer (score 5):

Just create a shortcut:

```
ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libperl.so.5.14
```

Comment: I used the same logic for Manjaro (Arch based) (Linux, right !? =D )! Ex.: `ln -s "/usr/lib/perl5/5.26/core_perl/CORE/libperl.so" "/usr/lib/libperl.so"`